# Symfony, CentOS, NGINX, php-fpm cache error

Tags: nginx, centos, php-fpm, symfony

I have been searching for two days on google and here and i tried every single solution out there to fix this issue but it seems to be that i am always missing something.
I have CentOS 7 installed and running on AWS Server along with NGINX php-fpm (php version 5.6).
my files are located at
/usr/share/nginx/html/website/

## /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
...
user centos;
...
```

and the server has been sat up using http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html
and its obiously working since i am able to reach my symfony through the ip.

## /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
....
user = centos
group = centos
....
listen.owner = centos
listen.group = centos
listen.mode = 0660
....
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
```

files permission in symfony project all assigned to centos:centos user
and var is writable.
though Terminal using user centos i can create/delete/remove/edit anything i have the whole access to all the files and folders inside of this project.
but for some reason when i hit the ip address of the server i have this error:

```
Failed to write cache file "/usr/share/nginx/html/website/apps/../var/marketplace/cache/dev/classes.php".
```

I added echo exec('whoami'); to app_dev.php
i get the centos user which means everything should be working smoothly.

and btw ../var is because i am having multiapps inside this symfony project
Any ideas what is wrong here???

for any other details log files or anything i am happy to provide.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this for a reference incase someone had something familiar it was permissions issue (not the user:group) but the access level permissions 
the files were 777 and the solution was to apply chmod 0777 instead of chmod 777.